Ошибка при считывании файла pdf из потока
Реализовал код для удаления штампа.
Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfContentEditor contentEditor = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfContentEditor();
Aspose.Pdf.Facades.StampInfo[] stampInfo = contentEditor.GetStamps(1);
contentEditor.BindPdf(@"C:\Downloads\Бух.pdf");
contentEditor.DeleteStamp(1, new int[] { stampInfo.FirstOrDefault().IndexOnPage });//.DeleteStampById(stampInfo.StampId);
contentEditor.Save(@"C:\Pr\Бух(v1).pdf");

Если документ считывается из файла то проблем нет,а если из потока ,то возникает ошибка Aspose.Pdf.InvalidPdfFileFormatException: "Incorrect file header".
Вот для примера
Stream  fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Dor\Б", FileMode.Open);
{

    Stream rs = new MemoryStream();
    rs.CopyTo(fileStream);
    Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfContentEditor contentEditor = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.PdfContentEditor();
    contentEditor.BindPdf(rs);
    Aspose.Pdf.Facades.StampInfo[] stampInfo = contentEditor.GetStamps(1);
    contentEditor.DeleteStamp(1, new int[] { stampInfo.FirstOrDefault().IndexOnPage });//.DeleteStampById(stampInfo.StampId);
    contentEditor.Save(rs); 
}

В чем может быть проблема?

Как вы думаете, судя по названию, метод CopyTo что делает? Правильно - копирует ваш (пустой) MemoryStream в FileStream. Видимо, вам нужно сделать наоборот: fileStream.CopyTo(rs);.

Не заметил. Спасибо большое)
